# How to add a GridView from PageResource to a pivotItem dynamically in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I'm trying to create mutiple PivotItems dynamically in the c# end and then for every PivotItem I want the set the content as a GridView which has a Datatemplate where elements are bound dynamically.

XAML code:

```
<Page.Resources>
<GridView x:Key="pivoteItemGV" 
    Margin="18,10,0,0"
     Background="#191919"
     SelectionMode="None">
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel MaxWidth="300">
                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemNameTB" Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemDescriptionTB" Text="{Binding ItemDescription}" 
                           TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemPriceTB" Text="{Binding ItemPrice}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
</Page.Resources>
```

And on the C# end

```
private void BindTheContentToPage()
{
    foreach(var categoryItem in contentResourceDictionary)
    {
        PivotItem categoryPivotItem = new PivotItem();
        categoryPivotItem.Header = categoryItem.Key;
        GridView gv = this.Resources["pivoteItemGV"] as GridView;
        categoryPivotItem.Content = gv;
        categoryPivotItem.DataContext = categoryItem.Value;
        mainContentPivot.Items.Add(categoryPivotItem);
    }
}
```

The app crashes at `categoryPivotItem.Content = gv;` stating ***Value does not fall within the expected range.***

Is what I'm doing right does? As I'm not sure whether multiple copies of Page.Resource contents, GridView in this case is duplicated.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't put visual elements directly into the `Resources` section as you did. You can put `DataTemplate`s there.
2. You need to set the `PivotItem.ContentTemplate` property to some `DataTemplate`. And set the `PivotItem.Content` property to your data object you want to bind to.

XAML code:

```
<Page.Resources>
 <DataTemplate x:Key="pivoteItemGVTemplate">
   <GridView 
     ItemsSource="{Binding}"
     Margin="18,10,0,0"
     Background="#191919"
     SelectionMode="None">
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel MaxWidth="300">
                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemNameTB" Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemDescriptionTB" Text="{Binding ItemDescription}" 
                           TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemPriceTB" Text="{Binding ItemPrice}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
  </GridView>
 </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

And in C# codebehind:

```
private void BindTheContentToPage()
{
    foreach(var categoryItem in contentResourceDictionary)
    {
        PivotItem categoryPivotItem = new PivotItem();
        categoryPivotItem.Header = categoryItem.Key;
        var template = this.Resources["pivoteItemGVTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
        categoryPivotItem.ContentTemplate = template;
        categoryPivotItem.Content = categoryItem.Value;
        mainContentPivot.Items.Add(categoryPivotItem);
    }
}
```

If your categoryItem.Value is a List of data objects, then add an attribute to the GridView (as I did in the XAML):

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. But there is one problem here you're assigning a datatemplate to content template but there is no content as my category.value doesn't contain a visual elements. Tried this but it doesnt display my contents

Comment: Maybe that's because you didn't set the ItemsSource of your GridView. If your categoryItem.Value is a List of data objects, then add an attribute to the GridView:
ItemsSource="{Binding}". I edited the answer with this new line

Comment: Yeah that was it! Thanks for your help!